# EF Core treats generated and handwritten projection expressions differnetly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm facing a very strange case and I've been beating my head against the wall for quite a few hours and I can't make sense of it.

The problem: Passing an expression that was generated in runtime by an expression visitor to the `Select` method would cause EF Core to throw an exception, while passing the **EXACT SAME** expression but this time written directly in the code would work perfectly.

Take a look at the below code, it's self-explanatory:

```
Expression<Func<Book, BookDto>> originalExpr = b => b.ToBookDto();

Expression<Func<Book, BookDto>> generatedExpr = new ExpandableVisitor().Visit(originalExpr) as Expression<Func<Book, BookDto>>;
Expression<Func<Book, BookDto>> sameAsGeneratedExpr = b => new BookDto()
{
    Id = b.Id,
    Name = b.Name,
    Author = new AuthorDto()
    {
        Id = b.Author.Id,
        Name = b.Author.Name,
        Books = b.Author.Books.Select(b => new BookDto()
        {
            Id = b.Id,
            Name = b.Name,
            Author = new AuthorDto()
            {
                Id = b.Author.Id,
                Name = b.Author.Name,
                Books = b.Author.Books.Select(b => b.ToBookDto()).ToList()
            }
        }).ToList()
    }
};

// The following boolean is TRUE, which shows that there is NO DIFFERENCE between the 2 expressions.
bool areExpressionsTheSame = generatedExpr.ToString() == sameAsGeneratedExpr.ToString(); 

IQueryable<BookDto> queryable = dbContext.Books.Select(generatedExpr); // Throws an exception
//IQueryable<BookDto> queryable = dbContext.Books.Select(sameAsGeneratedExpr); // Works properly

var dtos = queryable.Select(b => new BookDto()
{
    Name = b.Name,
    Author = new AuthorDto()
    {
        Name = b.Author.Name,
        Books = b.Author.Books.Select(b1 => new BookDto()
        {
            Name = b1.Name
        }).ToList()
    }
}).ToList(); // Note that this is the line that throws the exception, if that matters.
```

Using `generatedExpr` would cause the following exception to be thrown:

> "When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type
> 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null
> value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and
> change it to not visit children of this type."

I have run out of ideas about what's causing this, the expressions are the same, how could EF Core even tell the difference?!

Thanks in advance.

**Provider and version information:**

- EF Core version: 5.0.0 RC1
- Database provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Target framework: .NET 5.0

Comment: `expr1.ToString() == expr2.ToString()` does not necessarily mean that the two expressions are equal. Apparently in this case they are not. The problem is somewhere in your `ExpandableVisitor` class, so you must include it in the post if you want a concrete answer.

Comment: What is ".ToBookDto()". Because I'm going to assume this is an extension method in which case it's not "exactly the same".

Comment: I would suggest to use this extension https://github.com/agileobjects/ReadableExpressions and check what you have did wrong in your visitor.

Comment: @MindingData The expression visitor will receive that lambda expression `b => b.ToBookDto()` and generate from it what you see in the `sameAsGeneratedExpr` variable. That method is not relevant to my problem here.

Comment: @IvanStoev But I've also checked it with EF Core's `ExpressionEqualityComparer` and that returns true too.

Comment: @Arad  That does not prove they are equal either. There must be a difference, don't you agree? From the exception I can guess that most likely there is an unbound `ParameterExpression`, so neither `ToString()` (or tool showing readadble string), nor a comparer like EFC `ExpressionEqualityComparer` which compares parameters by name and type will report it. The problem is definitely in your visitor implementation.

Comment: >That method is not relevant to my problem here. 
Are you sure? I mean.. Because Extension Methods, private methods etc *will* cause all sorts of issues with EF Core projections.

Comment: What is `dtos` and how does it relate to your issue? Is the exception really thrown on the `Select` statement because I don't see how a `Visitor` is involved in that line.

Comment: @MindingData Well, no because, again, the extension method wouldn't be part of the projection expression that will be sent to the EF Core, that's why I have the expression visitor in the first place, it finds the extension method and replaces it with a certain expression that EF Core could easily translate to SQL and the final result (i.e. what **will be** sent to EF Core) is what you see in the `sameAsGeneratedExpr` variable. Nevermind, I found the problem and solved it. Thank you.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, I agree they must be different, but there is no apparent difference no matter how I measure their equality and that is what's annoying. I finally solved the problem by changing the expression visitor in such a way that it uses a unique parameter name for each parameter within the expression so that no 2 parameters have the same name. That apparently solved the problem, although I'm not really sure why since I have used duplicate parameter names in my directly-written lambda expression and EF didn't complain about that.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Thank you for mentioning that VS extension, my friend. It was really helpful and made the job easier!

Comment: @Arad, you are Wellcome. It saved me a months of debugging. Anyway there is alternative extension, never tried but, who knows https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Oh this one seems cool too! Has impressive features! Thanks again! ;)